# I'm looking for a LINQ solution to create a sub-list where items w/ duplicate property values are skipped

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-objects, vb.net-2010

The problem is: I have a list of objects, with some containing the same PlanId property value. I want to only grab the first occurrence of those and ignore the next object with that PlanId. The root problem is a View in the database, but it's tied in everywhere and I don't know if changing it will break a ton of stuff nearing a deadline, so I'm tossing in a hack for now.

So, if I have a list of PlanObjects like such.

- **Plan1.PlanId = 1**
- **Plan2.PlanId = 1**
- **Plan3.PlanId = 2**
- **Plan4.PlanId = 3**
- **Plan5.PlanId = 4**
- **Plan6.PlanId = 4**

I want to take a sub-list from that with LINQ (italics mean an item is not included)

- **Plan1.PlanId = 1**
- *Plan2.PlanId = 1*
- **Plan3.PlanId = 2**
- **Plan4.PlanId = 3**
- **Plan5.PlanId = 4**
- *Plan6.PlanId = 4*

For my needs, it doesn't matter which one is taken first. The Id is used to update a datbase record.

If I didn't explain that well enough, let me know and I'll edit the question. I think it makes sense though.

Comment: Thx for down-voting without explanation. If the idea is to make questions as helpful as possible, suggestions on how to make them better would be a good idea, if you're going to downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PlanObjects.GroupBy(p => p.PlanId).Select(r => r.First());
```

Comment: Any idea what this looks like in VB.Net?

Comment: PlanObjects.GroupBy(Function(x) x.PlanId).Select(function(r) r.First()) - should be something like that.

Comment: I never did any VB.Net, but I think what Alex wrote should be equivalent. Let us know.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer (and its comments) supplies the fluent interface solution. Here's the query syntax:

```
From p In PlanObjects Group By p.PlanId Into First Select First
```